# Can you compare two numbers stored as strings without knowing the datatype they represent?

Tags: c#, numbers, string-comparison

If I have two numbers represented as strings, "100" and "200", "100.1" and "200.1", how can I compare them to see if they which one is bigger?

Is there a generic Number.Compare(stringA, stringB) that will take care of datatype? I am using a database entry to determine validation rules, but the values could be long, decimal, floats, etc, so I can't create a single one.

Comment: Have you tried int.parse or int.tryparse?

Comment: What have you tried - if anything - thus far?  Have you tried an `OrdinalComparison`?

Comment: If you're not sure the decimal places, you could just convert them to doubles (with `double.Parse()`) and compare them that way.

Comment: What resolution do you need? The obvious answer down is to parse as double, but there are edge cases that blows (number too long, double representation has not enough significant digits).

Comment: @CAbbott This LIKELY works, but there are a lot of edge cases with large numbers where this does not work.

Comment: @Bob Question - what is the logic for the second number? Can it be 100.001 which would be 100 and 1? You say "two numbers", like 2 version numbers. In this case all the answers provided so far are simply - wrong.

Comment: @TomTom - I agree that there can be issues with doubles, that's why I had it as a comment with the qualifier of not knowing what the decimal places are. If there were < 3 decimal places, I would probably recommend `decimal.Parse()`

Comment: @TomTom, the second set of numbers is another example. The values I potentially can get are measurements up to 5 significant digits, and (from what I'm told) can be as large as 5000, which I probably should have expanded on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a generic Number.Compare(stringA, stringB) that will take
>   care of datatype?

No, there is no generic number comparison. You should know type of number. E.g. you can't parse string with floating point number "100.1" as integer. I'd go with parsing your strings as decimals or doubles (which will handle both "100" and "100.1"), and then comparing results. Use [Math.Max](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.max.aspx) to get larger from two numbers:

```
var max = Math.Max(Double.Parse("100.1"), Double.Parse("200"));
```

Answer (score 7):

Easy with linq

```
var numbers = new string[] {  "100" ,"200", "100.1" , "200.1" };
double max = numbers.Max(n => double.Parse(n));
```

Another solution with just string manipulation

```
int N = 100;
var max = numbers.Select(n => n.Split('.'))
                 .OrderByDescending(p => p[0].PadLeft(N,'0'))
                 .ThenByDescending(p => p.Length > 1 ? p[1].PadRight(N, '0') : "")
                 .Select(p => p.Length > 1 ? p[0] + "." + p[1] : p[0])
                 .First();
```

Answer (score 3):

This will also work if you declared the type as `decimal` even if the `numbers do not have a decimal point` just as if one had a `decimal point` this will work as well

```
var strNumbers = new string[] 
{ 
   "100", 
   "200",
   "100.1", 
   "200.1" 
};
decimal maxVal = numbers.Max(m => decimal.Parse(m));
```

Answer (score 0):

Any number represented as a string should be convertable to a double.

Answer (score 0):

You parse them. Either with an already existing parser, or manually, and the later MAY BE TRICKY because yo ustand up and tell me the formatting may be everthing, which could be scientific notation.

Answer (score -1):

use [int.tryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f02979c7.aspx%22int.TryParse%22) because this will ensure that if the string is not a number it will not blow up

Comment: muchObliged a bit of positive advice , before posting an answer it's better to make sure that the answer / solution is a viable one that being said you should test the code out on your machine before posting an answer, this is why some of the individuals here downvoted